# passing values between frames in ie5

Tags: javascript

None of the method mentioned below is passing the values between frames in IEv5.
(dFrames is the data frame to which im trying to pass the values)

```
alert("1 self.frames.dFrame :"+self.frames.dFrame);
                   alert("2 self.top.frames.dFrame :" +self.top.frames.dFrame);
                   alert("3 self.frames[2]:" +self.frames[2]);
                   alert("4 self.dFrame :"+self.dFrame);
                   alert("5 parent.frames.dFrame:"+parent.frames.dFrame);
                   alert("6 parent.dFrame:"+parent.dFrame);
                    alert("7 parent.frames['dFrame'] :"+parent.frames['dFrame']);
                    alert("8 frames[2] :"+frames[2]);
                    alert("9 top.frames[2] :"+top.frames[2]);
                    alert("10 window.frames[2] :"+window.frames[2]);
                    alert("11 window.parent.frames.dFrame :"+window.parent.frames.dFrame);
                    alert("12 window.top.dFrame :"+window.top.dFrame);
                    alert("13 window.top[2] :"+window.top[2]);
                    alert("14 window.parent.frames[2] :"+window.parent.frames[2]);
                    alert("15 window.parent[2] :"+window.parent[2]);
                    alert("16 parent.top.frames[2] :"+parent.top.frames[2]);
                    alert("17 top[2] :"+top[2]);
                    alert("18 window[2] :"+window[2]);
                    alert("19 parent[2] :"+parent[2]);
                    alert("20 window.dFrame :"+window.dFrame);
                    alert("21 top.frames['dFrame'] :"+top.frames['dFrame']);
                    alert("22 parent.frames['dFrame'] :"+parent.frames['dFrame']);
                    alert("23 frames['dFrame'] :"+frames['dFrame']);
```

i tried to alert each methods.hence a parameter 'undefined' after each.
can anyone help me find a method to pass values between frames in IE5?

Comment: Wow, I have to ask. IE5? What circumstances could lead you to still support a browser that old?

Comment: man, there is no IE5 anymore... even IE6 is already dead. http://ie6funeral.com/

Comment: Describe what your page structure is like. How else can we tell why it's not working? :) and reduce the codes that work on real browsers first.

Comment: When you say "between frames", do you mean the code above is used within one frame of a `frameset` and it wants to get a reference to another frame (and, presumably, call a function defined in the other frame)? Or are they `iframe` elements? Or...?

Comment: from one frame to another frame. i just need to know a global frame reference method for ie5.

Comment: It's been quite a while, but I'm pretty sure more than one of those methods worked in IE5.5 (I don't think I ever did frame-based JS stuff before 5.5). Are the contents of each frame and the parent page from the same domain?

Comment: IE5, 23 attempts to get a reference and all failed!? You certainly earn some badge for this ; ).

Answer (score 0):

Just give names for your `frame`s, then where ever you need a reference to some named `frame`, you can get it by `top.window.frame_name`.

As a sidenote, `frames` collection is a property of `document`, not `window`.